# swift iOS how get UICollectionViewCell for item

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have `UICollectionView` which feed from `myArray`.
I added `newItem` in `myArray` and I can see `newItem.image` in my `UICollectionView`. And now I need make some animation in the centre of this `UICollectionViewCell`.
How can I receive this cell (or indexPath for cell) with content `myArray[0]`?

```
myArray.insert(newItem, atIndex: 0)
myCollectionView.reloadData()

var indexPath = //?????? (it's my question)

if let index = indexPath {

    var cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(index) as! myCollectionViewCell
    self.myImageView.center = cell.center
    cell.itemImage.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(cell.donutsImage.transform, CGFloat(DegreesToRadians(90)))
}
```

Comment: try `var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)`

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
                
                if let index = indexPath {
                    
                    var cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(index) as! playCollectionViewCell
                    imageView.center = cell.center
                    cell.donutsImage.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(cell.donutsImage.transform, CGFloat(DegreesToRadians(360 - item.rotationAngle)))
                }

Comment: you refer this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1.

Comment: Dharmesh Dhorajiya, sorry, but your link doesn't has an answer for my question.
I able populate the cell by myArray's items. But how to find the cell through the index of item of myArray?..